# JavaScript will not calculate and input my results back into my form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Trying to pull information from my form input fields and calculate them using JavaScript. It does not seem to be working.

**HTML** (default1.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="multiplication.js" language="javascript"></script>  
<form>
    <table>
        <tr><!--Row 2-->
            <td class="tdSize7">
                <input class="input" name="name1" type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td class="tdSize7">
                <input class="input" name="source1" type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td class="tdSize8">
                <p>&#36;</p>
            </td>
            <td class="tdSize9">
                <input class="input" name="income1" type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td class="tdSize8">
                <p>X12</p>
            </td>
            <td class="tdSize8">
                <p>&#36;</p>
            </td>
            <td class="tdSize9">
                <input name="ann1" disabled="disabled"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td class="tdSize9"><input class="inputSize2" name="" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="addme(this.form)"/></td> 
    </table>
</form>
```

**JavaScript** (multiplication.js)

```
function addme(form) {
//Constant Variables
    const twelve = Number (12);
    const fourHun = Number (400);
    const fourHunEighty = Number (480);

//Monthly  Income 1
    var income1 = Number(frm.income1.value);
    var val = income1 * twelve;
    frm.ann1.value = val;
}
```

My JavaScript will not calculate and input my results back into my form.
This is just a sample of my code. I am hoping this will tell you enough and help you, in helping me fixing my problem.

Comment: Are you using any server-side code? That's normally how you manage/manipulate data from a form.

Comment: You're using `frm` inside the function, but passing `form` as an argument. Choose one.

Comment: First: any good reason you are not using jQuery?
Second: why on Earth do you have constants named as numbers? If it's always 12 (or 400 or 480) just use the number, not constant.

Comment: 1) You are passing in "form", but trying to access a variable named "frm".  2) You cannot access elements on a form like "frm.income1".  3)  You should give each of the input elements a unique ID attribute and then you can access them using document.getElementById().

Comment: Not really related to your issue, but you have terrible constant names. Your constants should be more meaningful. if your constant for 12 is just "twelve", you might as well just use 12.

Comment: @SlipperyPete Your second and third points are not true, you can access form elements by name like that since forms were introduced in HTML. See http://jsfiddle.net/dvBVR/

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks, I stand corrected.

Comment: @SlipperyPete in your jsfiddle add a second <input name="theinput" value="thevalue2"> and see the result.

Comment: @HMarioD That was *my* jsfiddle, and yes, a second input with the same name will cause the script to alert "undefined". Just to be clear, I'm not advocating that we all should be using DOM level 0 methods to get form elements references, I'm just saying it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you intend to use `form` instead of `frm`? That is part of your problem

Try:

```
var income1 = Number(form.income1.value);
var val = income1 * twelve;
form.ann1.value = val;
```

Or change

```
function addme(form)
```

to

```
function addme(frm)
```

Comment: I corrected all the code but after a curtain part my javascript want calculate and return my values.  ? (New to the forms)... Should i ask the question here or post a new question?

Comment: @Spooner Looks like you should post a new question.